# Select anidado con una única tabla

Tags: php, javascript, mysql

Tengo que hacer un select que cuando un usuario seleccione una opción, se active en otro select las opciones relacionadas con el primer select, el problema con esto, es que la base que estoy usando solo tiene una tabla para esto, es decir, no puedo discriminar los tipos de select por id's, como debería ser, además de ser estaticos, acá les dejo una porsión del código:

```html
<p>
 <label for="exampleInputFile">Tipo de Arma:</label>
 <select for="exampleInputEmail" class="form-control" name="tipo_arma">
  <option value="Revolver" selected>Revolver</option>
  <option value="Pistola">Pistola</option>
  <option value="Escopeta">Escopeta</option>
 </select>
</p>
<p>
 <label for="exampleInputFile">Calibre:</label>
 <select name="calibre" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
  <option value="32">.32</option>
  <option value="38" selected>.38</option>
  <option value="38corto">.38 corto</option>
  <option value="38largo">.38 largo</option>
  <option value="38especial">.38 especial</option>
  <option value="3,87">3,87</option>
  <option value="7,65mm">7,65 mm</option>
  <option value="2mm">2 mm</option>
  <option value="9mm">9 mm</option>
  <option value="12">12</option>
  <option value="16">16</option>
  <option value="20">20</option>
 </select>
</p>
<p>
 <label for="exampleInputFile">Marca del Arma:</label>
 <select name="marca_arma" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
  <option value="llamaIndumil">llama Indumil</option>
  <option value="Smith&wesson" selected>Smith & wesson</option>
  <option value="Colt">Colt</option>
  <option value="Taurus">Taurus</option>
  <option value="Ruby">Ruby</option>
  <option value="Jericho">Jericho</option>
  <option value="Cz">Cz</option>
  <option value="Walter">Walter</option>
  <option value="Mossberg">Mossberg</option>
  <option value="Remington">Remington</option>
  <option value="Hatsan">Hatsan</option>
  <option value="Stevens">Stevens</option>
  <option value="Indumil">Indumil</option>
  <option value="HighEstandar">High Estandar</option>
 </select>
</p>
```

Después de intentar varias cosas, llegué a esta solución, agregando un par de cosas, si alguien tiene una solución resumida o mejor, bienvenida es.

```html
<script>
 function TipoArma() {

 var num = document.getElementById("num");

 if (num.value == "Revolver"){

   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<option value='.32'>.32</option><option value='.38'>.38</option><option value='.38corto'>.38 corto</option><option value='.38largo'>.38 largo</option><option value='.38especial'>.38 especial</option>";

  document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<option value='llamaIndumil'>llama Indumil</option><option value='Smith&Wesson'>Smith & Wesson</option> <option value='Colt'>Colt</option><option value='Taurus'>Taurus</option><option value='Ruby'>Ruby</option>";

  }

  if (num.value == "Pistola"){

   document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<option value='3,87'>3,87</option> <option value='7,65mm'>7,65 mm</option> <option value='2mm'>2 mm</option> <option value='9mm'>9 mm</option>";

            document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<option value='Jericho'>Jericho</option> <option value='Cz'>Cz</option> <option value='Walter'>Walter</option>";
         }

         if (num.value == "Escopeta"){

             document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "<option value='12'>12</option> <option value='16'>16</option> <option value='20'>20</option>";

         document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = "<option value='Mossberg'>Mossberg</option> <option value='Remington'>Remington</option> <option value='Hatsan'>Hatsan</option> <option value='Stevens'>Stevens</option> <option value='Indumil'>Indumil</option> <option value='HighEstandar'>High Estandar</option> <option value='Bernardelli'>Bernardelli</option>";
         }


     }
    </script>

     <p>
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Tipo de Arma:</label>
    <select onchange="TipoArma()" id="num" class="form-control" name="tipo_arma">
     <option value="" selected>Seleccione el tipo de arma...</option>
     <option value="Revolver">Revolver</option>
     <option value="Pistola">Pistola</option>
     <option value="Escopeta">Escopeta</option>
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Calibre:</label>
    <select id='demo' name="calibre" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
     
    </select>
    </p>
    <p>
    <label for="exampleInputFile">Marca del Arma:</label>
    <select id='demo2' name="marca_arma" class="form-control" id="exampleInputEmail1">
     
    </select>
    </p>
```

Comment: Hay varias preguntas en el sitio sobre cómo tener select dependientes, ¿has mirado si alguna de las soluciones te vale? Si no, deberías añadir lo que intentaste y los errores/dificultades que hacen que no funcione. Además, deberías añadir más información específica a tu pregunta: ¿Dónde está el código JavaScript relacionado? ¿O el PHP que lee los datos de la base de datos? Lee [ask] y cómo crear un [mcve] para más información.

Comment: Hasta donde veo no lees nada de la base de datos, solo lo creas con javascript, ademas ni siquiera has mostrado la estructura de la tabla de donde supuestamente leerias la informacion

Comment: " la base que estoy usando solo tiene una tabla para esto, es decir, no puedo discriminar los tipos de select por id's, como debería ser, además de ser estaticos", por eso no puse nada de la base de datos.